# How to copy content file to bin directory after every change in VS.NET 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, build, solution, post-build-event

I have highly modular VS.NET 2013 solution with one (almost empty) ASP.NET MVC application and several class libraries (aka modules) containing: code, html, css, js files, etc.

Everything works fine, but the only problem is that content files in every module have to be copied to ASP.NET MVC application's bin directory so that appliaction can use it.

Now I use the simplest solution for it and marked all content files' build action as "Content" with "Copy always" setting. But every time I change one of content files I have to re-build solution to update content files in bin directory.

How to trigger copy file action immediately after editing it?

Comment: Can't you use linked files instead? I understand there may be scenarios where linked files cannot be used but just wondering whether you have considered this?

Comment: Yes, but it won't work in my case because I have runtime which loads modules that internally use content files. Thanks to it I can reuse modules in different applications without manually linking all content files.

Comment: @johnnyno did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you need some external tools to monitor those file and copy them when changes occurs.

You can't do it with visual studio (without building).

I think that [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) with `/mon` or `/mot` option could do the trick

From: http://www-pc.uni-regensburg.de/systemsw/tools/robocopy.doc

> Monitoring a Directory Tree Using the /MON:n and /MOT:m switches you
>   can Monitor the source directory tree for changes, and copy changes as
>   and when they occur. The /MON:n switch specifies the minimum number of
>   changes that must occur before running again. The /MOT:m switch
>   specifies the minimum time, in minutes, that must elapse before
>   running again.  If you only specify one of these switches, the other
>   is assumed to have a value of 1.
>
> When Monitoring is specified, Robocopy never terminates. Instead, it
>   enters a loop that performs a normal Robocopy pass and then monitors
>   the source directory tree for changes, until both n changes have been
>   detected and m minutes have elapsed. When both conditions are met,
>   another Robocopy pass is started. This whole process of copying and
>   monitoring is repeated, ad infinitum, until the user manually
>   terminates the Robocopy process.